# How to handle a null/empty string input in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, null, codeblocks

In Java, this can be used:

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
String x = s.next();
if(x == null || x.length() == 0)
     System.out.println("Please enter something") ;
```

which says "Please enter something" if the user hits the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key without typing anything.

How to do this in C++ using Codeblocks or Visual Studio?

Comment: Are you sure that's java?  `cout <<` is definitely a c++ thing.

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide at least a minimal example of how you'd do it in C++, so that we can correct eventual errors. Stackoverflow is here to help you, not to do your work.

Comment: Java or C++? It can't be both, no matter what you try.

Comment: If you're going to ask questions like this, describe what you're trying to do instead of posting syntax and idioms from a language that is not C++.

Comment: Are you sure it's C++? `Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);`is not C++.

Comment: sorry, at first i wrote cout << by mistake... i edited that.

Comment: @manni66 , that is not c++. that's an example of java.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent in C++ is more-or-less:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main() {
  string something;
  bool more = true;
  cout << "Enter something: ";

  while (more) {
    getline(cin, something);

    if (something.empty()) {
      cout << "Please enter something: ";
    }
    else {
      more = false;
    }
  }

  cout << "You entered '" << something << "'." << endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The `more` variable is not needed. Use a `do..while` loop and `break` the loop when the input is not empty, eg: `do { getline(cin, something); if (!something.empty()) break; cout << "Please enter something: "; } while (true);`

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Scanner` parses whitespace-separated items.
In C++, you need to first read an entire line and then take it apart.
Something like this:

```
std::string x;
while (std::getline(std::cin, x) && x.empty())
{
    std::cout << "Please enter something" << std::endl;
}
std::istringstream is(x);
std::string y;
while (is >> y)
{
    // Do something with each "part".
}
```